# BEM Confusions with naming elements

Tags: css, sass, components, bem

I have been using BEM on a project at work for keeping my CSS more modular and come across a few situations I feel a need for a bit of clarification on:

Context dependent styles. I keep coming across a need to change a style of a module/component dependent upon a class on a parent item.

Say I am style a product list. I have my `.product-list` component and inside that all my `.product-list__item`'s. The `.product-list__item`'s then might have an `<h3>` inside as the product title.

My questions are:

- Should the `.product-list__item` also have a class of `.item`?
- Should the title inside the product have the following classes:
- - `.item__title` ?
- - `.product-list__item__title` ?

Say the item also had a description box within and that contained the price:

- Should the description have:
- - `.item__description` ?
- - `.product-list__item__description` ?
- Should the price have:
- - `.item__description__price` ?
- - `.description__price` ?
- - `.price` ?

I do subcomponents sort of need their own component name added separatley ie: `.item` or `.description`. I'm guessing that they need them as where else do they get their styling applied?

Also, If I had the above I would have a `.product-list` component whcihsounds fine but if sub components have their own component name added as a class such as `.item` then that is not very descriptive of itself is it?

I know thei may sound complicated but I am serious about being confused here and would love to hear your opinions. I ahve read a ton of articles on BEM and not one explains this sort of thing.

Neil

Comment: Why has this been down voted? I am asking a serious naming convention question.

Comment: Naming conventions are a personal choice: do what makes sense for your project.  This type of question only results opinionated answers.

Comment: That's what I am after though.

Comment: You're asking in the wrong place then. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @cimmanon BEM is (almost) all about naming conventions, so I think this is a valid question: it asks how apply a well defined methodology to a project.

Comment: outwardly BEM appears to just be a naming convention, but there is a right way and a wrong way to apply it, so a question about how to apply it is not a how should I name stuff question - again a question is closed because users can't see the nuances, this is a failure of the Stack Overflow moderation process

Comment: I don't understand why this has been closed. The question being asked is not opinion-based. It's a strict naming convention with a right and wrong way of doing things. If he'd asked 'How should I class these elements?' then yes. That would have been opinion-based, but he is asking specifically for BEM.

Comment: I am one more person, who is against the question closing. Maybe there is people who could answer the question. And there are people who also have such a problem or just an answer would be useful for them.

Comment: It's definitely can be objectively answered: https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-create-elements-of-elements-block__elem1__elem2

Answer (score 9):

According to BEM methodology there are no elements of elements so instead of `product-list__item__title` you should use `product-list__item-title`.

As for context dependent styles you can use either cascade (and place styles to parent file) or mix as in your examples. Rule is simple: as soon as you find yourself using some *item* somewhere without its parent *block* — make it separate block and use mixes but if items are absolutely useless without parent using cascade makes more sense.